# Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query Update State on Post mutation

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am using RTK Query to call an API to get data using a POST method. How can I update the redux state every time I call the API to get data?
I am getting an error in updateQueryData that *getUser is not assignable to parameter of type never*.

```js
export const apiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: app.apiHost,
  }),
  tagTypes: ["User"],
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getUser: build.mutation({
      query: (body) => ({
        url: `/getuser`,
        method: "POST",
        body,
      }),
      providesTags: ["User"],
      async onQueryStarted(args, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
          const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
          const patchResult = dispatch(
          api.util.updateQueryData('getUser', args, (draft) => {
            Object.assign(draft, data)
          })
          )
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("error... ", err);
        }
      },
    }),
    updateUser: build.mutation({
      query: () => ({
        url: `/updateUser`,
        method: "POST",
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["User"],
    }),
  }),
});
```

Comment: The API slice state will be updated when any query/mutation is effected. Are you asking how to save a query/mutation result elsewhere in your Redux store? What do you want/need to update in the store? Please [edit] to clarify what the issue/problem is or what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: After calling the api is successful, I want to get the current state or cache data and append the new data. i am using post method above to get the data with request body.
I tried the updateQueryData in onQueryStarted but it is not working.

Comment: Using `updateQueryData`, e.g. a [Pessimistic Update](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/manual-cache-updates#pessimistic-updates), is likely what you want. Can you [edit] to provide a [mcve] of the code you are/were trying to use and clarify more specifically what didn't work as expected?

Comment: Hi updated code above, i use pessimistic update but i am getting an error when using updateQueryData it is not updating the state.

Comment: What is `patch` in the code? Should `Object.assign(draft, patch)` be `Object.assign(draft, data)` so you are passing the fulfilled data to the query cache you want to update?

Answer (score 0):

error is that updateQueryData does not allow to update same method. in this case i am inside getUser endpoint and in updateQueryData i am accessing same getUser endpoint.